# Simultaneously animated cubes using KeyFrameTracks in ThreeJS

Tags: animation, three.js

I would like to display two different cubes animated via KeyFrameTracks. Following examplary KeyFrame Three.js code has been adopted. How can I integrate a second animated cube moved via KeyFrameTracks? Thx

```
// create an animation sequence with the tracks
// If a negative time value is passed, the duration will be    calculated from the times of the passed tracks array

var clip = new THREE.AnimationClip( 'Action', 3, [ scaleKF, positionKF, quaternionKF, colorKF, opacityKF ] );

// setup the AnimationMixer
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );

// create a ClipAction and set it to play
var clipAction = mixer.clipAction( clip );
clipAction.play();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use [AnimationObjectGroup](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/animation/AnimationObjectGroup). An instance of this class represents a group of objects that receives a shared animation state. After creating the group, you add the respective meshes to it. In the next step, you pass this group to the animation mixer as its root object.

```
const animationGroup = new THREE.AnimationObjectGroup();

animationGroup.add( mesh1 );
animationGroup.add( mesh2 );

const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( animationGroup );
```

https://threejs.org/examples/misc_animation_groups

`three.js R104`

Comment: Thank you, would it also be possible to animate two or more cubes differentally using KeyFrameTracks (i.e. array containing time data and array containing position data)? E.g. one cube moving left in two seconds and the other cube moving right in 3 seconds starting at the same point in time. Thx

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. But consider to use `tween.js` or a similar library if you create such (simple) animations from scratch. It is also used in various `three.js` examples like https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable